# How to draw a part of a window into a memory device context?

Tags: c++, c, gdi

I'm using simple statements to keep it, er, simple:

- The screen goes from 0, 0 to 1000, 1000 (screen coordinates).
- A window goes from 100, 100 to 900, 900 (screen coordinates).
- I have a memory device context that goes from 0, 0 to 200, 200 (logical coordinates).

I need to send a WM_PRINT message to the window. I can pass the device context to the window via WM_PRINT, but I cannot pass which part of its window it should draw into the device context.

Is there some way to alter the device context that will result in the window drawing a specific part of itself into the device context (say, its bottom right portion from 700, 700 to 900, 900)?

(This is all under plain old GDI and in C or C++. Any solution must be too.)

Please note:
This problem is part of a larger solution in which the device context size is fixed and speed is crucial, so I cannot draw the window in full into a separate device context and blit the part I want from the resultant full bitmap into my device context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [SetViewportOrgEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to specify the device context coordinates that will be mapped to the window's origin:

```
SetViewportOrgEx(yourDC, -600, -600, NULL);
```

Since your window's size is `800x800`, offsetting the DC's coordinate system by `-600x-600` will result in the `200x200` bottom right area of the window being drawn, and the rest being clipped.